# Проблема с кириллицей в JavaFX

Tags: javafx, unicode, интерфейс

Неправильно отображаются русские символы в объектах javafx.scene.control.TextField, javafx.scene.control.Button (думаю, и других тоже).

Если в поле ввода ввести слово **ПРИВЕТ**, то вместо него будет отрисовываться слово **ОПЗБДС**.

Также если у кнопки с помощью метода *setText(*"**БВГ**"*)* установить текст **БВГ**, то отрисовываться будет текс **АБВ**, то есть в кодовой таблице, которая используется для отображения текста компонента, положение кириллических символов сдвинуто на 1 по сравнению с используемой **UTF-8**.

Если же вывести в консоль результат метода *getText()*, вызванного у экземпляра кнопки, то выведено будет именно **БВГ**.

[Скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSz64.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт.

Можно было догадаться, что для отрисовки используется конкретный шрифт, в котором и есть это несоответствие. Проблема решилась установкой значения шрифта.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru"));
```

Comment: Опять же, все было испробовано, но увы. Работает только смена шрифта.